# Transactional Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW not work

Tags: spring, spring-boot, transactions, spring-data-jpa, spring-transactions

I try save list of entities to Oracle Db.

```
@Transactional
public void save() {
//logick
for (QuittanceType quittanceType : quittance) {
       quittancesService.parseQuittance(quittanceType);
     }
//logick
  }
```

On each step I call this method:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void parseQuittance(QuittanceType quittance) {
    try {

        //logick create payToChargeDb
        paymentToChargeService.saveAndFlush(payToChargeDb);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Ignore.", e);
    }
}
```

and method

```
        @Override
        public PaymentsToCharge saveAndFlushIn(PaymentsToCharge paymentsToCharge) {
            return paymentToChargeRepository.saveAndFlush(paymentsToCharge);
        }
```

When I try save entity with constraint My main transaction rollback and I get stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-02290: CHECK integrity constraint violated(MYDB.PAYMENTS_TO_CHARGE_CHK1)
```

But I want skip not success entities and save success. I marck my method

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
```

and it look like this:

```
@Transactional
@Override
public void parseQuittance(QuittanceType quittance) {
    try {

        //logick create payToChargeDb
        paymentToChargeService.saveAndFlushInNewTransaction(payToChargeDb);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("Ignore.", e);
    }
}
```

and

```
@Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)
    @Override
    public PaymentsToCharge saveAndFlushInNewTransaction(PaymentsToCharge paymentsToCharge) {
        return paymentToChargeRepository.saveAndFlush(paymentsToCharge);
    }
```

But when I try save entity with constraint I not get exception and not enter to catcj block. just stop working debugging and the application continues to work. I do not get any errors. and as if rollback is happening

Comment: Is your  `saveAndFlushInNewTransaction` part of the same class as `parseQuittance`?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `@Transactional` annotation from `save()` and `parseQuittance()` methods and leave it only on `saveAndFlushInNewTransaction()`?

Answer (score 0):

The proxy created by `@Transactional` does not intercept calls within the object.

> In proxy mode (which is the default), only external method calls
>   coming in through the proxy are intercepted. This means that
>   self-invocation (in effect, a method within the target object calling
>   another method of the target object) does not lead to an actual
>   transaction at runtime even if the invoked method is marked with
>   @Transactional. Also, the proxy must be fully initialized to provide
>   the expected behavior, so you should not rely on this feature in your
>   initialization code (that is, @PostConstruct).

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative

The same documentation r[ecommends use of AspectJ if you want this behaviour](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/data-access.html#transaction-declarative-aspectj).

Comment: `quittancesService.parseQuittance` and `paymentToChargeService.saveAndFlush` apparently they are in different service classes so the `@Transactional` annotation should work.

Comment: The OP has not posted any class structure. I think downvotes are unwarranted, as this behaviour can be a "gotcha", and given the lack of information, could be the answer.

Comment: The downvote is not mine. Although not very clear, the methods in question belong to different classes (see my comment above) so this answer is based on a false assumption.